# Как выделить резервную память СИ

Tags: c, указатели, память

Есть задача: избежать краха программы при недостатке памяти.
Пример:

```
TYPE* a = malloc(NUMELEMS*sizeof(TYPE));
if (a == NULL){
    /* Здесь я бы хотел присвоить указателю адрес
       на резервную, мною раньше зарезервированную память */
}
```

Как собственно объявить эту самую резервную память?
Пока что думаю сделать так:

```
void* MemoryParachute = calloc(100, 32);
/* 100 резервных участков по 32 байта */
...
if (a == NULL){
    a = MemoryParachute;
    *a = VALUE;
}
```

Может быть есть какие-нибудь готовые решения?

> ... получить указатель на следующий узел списка. Чтобы избежать этой проблемы, перед удалением текущего элемента убедитесь, что у вас есть указатель на следующий элемент списка.
>
> ***Выделите «запасной парашют» памяти.*** Если в программе используется динамическая память, необходимо избежать проблемы ее внезапной нехватки, приводящей к исчезновению пользовательских данных на бескрайних просторах оперативной памяти. Один из способов дать вашей программе запас прочности — заранее выделить «парашют» памяти. Определите, какой объем памяти нужен программе для сохранения работы, освобождения ресурсов и аккуратного завершения. Зарезервируйте эту память в начале работы программы как запасной парашют и оставьте ее в покое. Когда памяти станет не хватать, раскройте резервный парашют — освободите эту память и завершите работу программы.

<sup>Цитату взял из книги «Совершенный код» С. Макконелла</sup>

Comment: Что такое `(TYPE*)&MemoryParachute[0];`? Откуда взялось такое нагромождение операторов (к тому же некорректное)?

Comment: @AnT Взять ссылку на первые 32 байта MemoryParachute. Привести их к типу переменной a. Вроде все правильно.

Comment: Где тут фигурируют "32 байта"? Каком образом в этом выражении компилятор узнает про 32? В любом случае, в языке С запрещается применять оператор `[]` к указателю на тип `void` (или на любой другой неполный тип). В вашем случае вам достаточно просто сделать `a = MemoryParachute;` и все. Откуда и зачем тут взялись операторы `[]`, `&` да еще и каст - не ясно.

Comment: @AnT Да, согласен: & и [] тут лишние.

Comment: ...Как и операция приведения типа. И здесь, и в том числе в изначальном вызове `malloc`. Приведение типа на вызове функции выделения памяти - дурной стиль в С.

Comment: @AnT т.е. все автоматически приведется?

Comment: Разумеется. В С тип `void *` неявно приводим к указателю на любые данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделение резервной памяти ничем не отличается от выделения в любом другом случае. Разница лишь в том, что выделение это должно быть выполнено как можно раньше, пока никто другой нужную память не успех захватить. Т.о. делать какие-то различия вида `malloc` - в обычном случае, `calloc` - для резервной памяти особого смысла нет.

Как будет размечаться эта резервная память сильно зависит от задачи. Например, если все данные однотипны (или хотя бы имеют одинаковый размер), то можно завести отдельную таблицу, которая будет говорить о занятости/свободности ячейки в резервной памяти. Если данные разнотипны, может потребовать какая-то более сложная схема со списками, например. В общем, придётся создать свой упрощённый менеджер памяти, который будет сообщать где свободно, где занято и сколько ещё осталось.

Comment: Я понимаю, но я хочу заранее выделить, допустим, 10 мб памяти, чтобы в случае нехватки можно было взять и использовать какой-либо кусочек от этой, уже полученной, памяти.

Comment: @IvanovDmitry уточнил ответ.

Comment: @IvanovDmitry, в статье говорится немного о другом. В первую очередь о том, что при тотальной нехватке памяти можно освободить этот кусок, чтобы программа смогла "нормально"-аварийно завершиться, при этом позаботиться о сохранении данных (этому  может помешать дефицит памяти). Если вы хотите написать свой собственный менеджер памяти в отдельно взятом куске - это совсем другая задача.

Comment: @alexolut Да, спасибо! Для каждого мною определенного типа данных сделаю резерв)

Comment: Похоже всем надо читать как работают операционные системы. Потому что от того, на какой из них запущен код, могут быть самые интересные случаи. Например, Linux, казалось бы что же проще?! `malloc()` там NULL практически никогда не возвращает, хотя памяти может и не быть. Или другие системы с *lazy resource management*. Помимо этого, надо понимать разницу с какой памятью (указателем на память) вы работаете. Если это физическая память, то это одно, а ежели виртуальная, то тут возможны варианты.

Comment: @0andriy Не могли бы вы какую-нибудь литературу по этой теме порекомендовать?